# react native expo - Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: react-native, expo

In order to add OTA updates functionality, I installed `expo-updates` package and before that I configured `expo-modules@latest` in my react native bare project. Everything worked fine, build successfully, but when I execute the command `eas build -p android --profile preview`, it crashes/build-fails after 6 mins due to the following error:

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:compileReleaseKotlin'.
[stderr] > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
[stderr]    > Compilation error. See log for more details
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 4m 53s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

I searched for hours related to this issue and found something similar here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19259#issuecomment-1259724391, applied the changes, and it is still throwing the same build everytime... Everything works in development though, no crashes there...

My env:

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.0",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.6",
  },
  ...
}
```

I am not able to create a build due to this error, if someone could help, I would really appreciate it!

Feel free to ask any more details if needed!